# Unable to install 'web3[tester]' - Cannot open source file: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c'

Tags: web3.py

Version: web3==5.13.0
Python: 3.9.0
OS: win 10

`pip freeze` output -

```
attrs==20.3.0
backcall==0.2.0
base58==2.0.1
bitarray==1.2.2
blake2b-py==0.1.3
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.4
cytoolz==0.11.0
decorator==4.4.2
eth-abi==2.1.1
eth-account==0.5.4
eth-hash==0.2.0
eth-keyfile==0.5.1
eth-keys==0.3.3
eth-rlp==0.2.1
eth-typing==2.2.2
eth-utils==1.9.5
hexbytes==0.2.1
idna==2.10
ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1
ipython==7.19.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.17.2
jsonschema==3.2.0
lru-dict==1.1.6
multiaddr==0.0.9
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
netaddr==0.8.0
parsimonious==0.8.1
parso==0.7.1
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==3.0.8
protobuf==3.14.0
py-ecc==4.1.0
py-geth==2.4.0
pycryptodome==3.9.9
Pygments==2.7.2
pypiwin32==223
pyrsistent==0.17.3
pywin32==300
requests==2.25.0
rlp==2.0.1
semantic-version==2.8.5
six==1.15.0
sortedcontainers==2.3.0
toolz==0.11.1
traitlets==5.0.5
trie==2.0.0a5
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.2
varint==1.0.2
wcwidth==0.2.5
web3==5.13.0
websockets==8.1
```

The code which produced the error - `pip install 'web3[tester]'`
The full output of the error -

```
$ pip install 'web3[tester]'


Requirement already satisfied: web3[tester] in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (5.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-typing<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: hexbytes<1.0.0,>=0.1.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages 
(from web3[tester]) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (0.7.0a1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<4,>=3.10.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (3.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.6 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages 
(from web3[tester]) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (2.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets<9.0.0,>=8.1.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32>=223; platform_system == "Windows" in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (223)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (1.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: py-geth<3,>=2.4.0; extra == "tester" in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from web3[tester]) (2.4.0)
Collecting eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"
  Using cached eth_tester-0.5.0b3-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: multiaddr>=0.0.7 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from 
ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1->web3[tester]) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from protobuf<4,>=3.10.0->web3[tester]) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parsimonious<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6->web3[tester]) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3[tester]) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3[tester]) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keys!=0.3.2,<0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3[tester]) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: rlp<3,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3[tester]) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages 
(from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3[tester]) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome<4,>=3.6.6; extra == "pycryptodome" in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0->web3[tester]) (3.9.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3[tester]) (2020.11.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3[tester]) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3[tester]) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3[tester]) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3[tester]) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3[tester]) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3[tester]) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32>=223; platform_system == "Windows"->web3[tester]) (300)
Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1; implementation_name == "cpython" in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5->web3[tester]) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: semantic-version>=2.6.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from py-geth<3,>=2.4.0; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (2.8.5)
Collecting py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"
  Using cached py_evm-0.3.0a20-py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: base58 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1->web3[tester]) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: varint in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1->web3[tester]) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.7.0a1->web3[tester]) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1; implementation_name == "cpython"->eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5->web3[tester]) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions<1.0.0,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (0.4.3)
Collecting pyethash<1.0.0,>=0.1.27
  Using cached pyethash-0.1.27.tar.gz (38 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: trie==2.0.0-alpha.5 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (2.0.0a5)
Requirement already satisfied: py-ecc<5.0.0,>=1.4.7 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (4.1.0)
Collecting eth-bloom<2.0.0,>=1.0.3
  Using cached eth_bloom-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property<2,>=1.5.1 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blake2b-py<0.2,>=0.1.2 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages 
(from py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers<3,>=2.1.0 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from trie==2.0.0-alpha.5->py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions<4,>=3.7.4 in c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\lib\site-packages (from trie==2.0.0-alpha.5->py-evm==0.3.0a20; extra == "py-evm"->eth-tester[py-evm]==v0.5.0-beta.3; extra == "tester"->web3[tester]) (3.7.4.3)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyethash, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyethash, eth-bloom, py-evm, eth-tester
    Running setup.py install for pyethash ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iver41qv\\pyethash\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iver41qv\\pyethash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3sfswv97\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyethash'
         cwd: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iver41qv\pyethash\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyethash' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\libethash
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\python
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
/DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/libethash/internal.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/libethash/internal.obj -Isrc/ -std=gnu99 -Wall
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
    internal.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1833): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1833): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
/DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/libethash/io.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/libethash/io.obj -Isrc/ -std=gnu99 -Wall
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
    io.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1833): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1833): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
/DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/libethash/io_win32.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/libethash/io_win32.obj -Isrc/ -std=gnu99 -Wall
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
    io_win32.c
    c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iver41qv\\pyethash\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iver41qv\\pyethash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3sfswv97\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asus\desktop\ayush\programs\ethereum\starting_out\venv\include\site\python3.9\pyethash' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks to everyone for their time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have installed and possibly utilized the same pip packages within separately activated virtual python environments which leads to multiple folder locations and multiple versions of the same package. I would comb through your install history and file system hiearchy to figure out which pip packages you should retain and which you should uninstall to fix the issue.

The win 32c error at the end of the output appears to be the result of installing a  64 bit program in the Program Files x86 folder rather then the Program Files. Program Files folder is for 64x and and x86 is for 32bit and windows cannot see 64bit programs in the x86 folder.

Also, I strongly suggest you utilize either WSL2 along with VSCode or something than runs on Linux because webapps can be very very difficult to successfully develop complex web apps, especially those that are Web3 Dapps, within a Windows environment. This is from my own personally experience.

******additional response/follow up

No problem!

In order to list installed Pip packages, it’s simply

Pip list or Python3 -m Pip list

32bit/62bit apps should be accessible via sql server but definitely look into it further

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I figured out the issue was because ethash doesn't support Windows. Linux certainly makes sense/
But could you kindly tell me if I could see all my pip downloads in a place and also how to make sure that 64 bit programs are not stored in x86 folder?